# Can I get Last write time of a file in SharePoint via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Is it possible to get when was the last WRITE time of a file in a document library by using Powershell?

```
$url = "http://myserver/sites/mysite/shared%20documents/myfile.xlsx"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$lastWriteTimestamp = #...
```

Comment: For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the SharePoint Stack Exchange (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @P S: Given that the question relates to cmdlet functions specific to PowerShell, I don't see there being much help at the SharePoint SE portal.

This question can't be answered without someone who has awareness of PowerShell, so they would likely have sent the asker right back here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's recorded in the [SPFile.TimeLastModified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.timelastmodified.aspx) Property.
I don't have access to a SharePoint install at this moment to test, but the script would look something like this pseudo code.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://mywebname/"
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]
$item = $list.GetItemById(1)
$lastWriteTime = $item.TimeLastModified
```

**Edit:**
To Clarify; the SharePoint PowerShell snapin only works on servers with SharePoint installed, it cannot be used remotely. It also requires that the user has the SPShellAdmin permission on the relevant database.

If you need to access that property from a remote session, you will have to use the CSOM (client side object model), which still requires you to have access to the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll.

Here is a pseudo code version for accessing with CSOM, again I don't have access to a SharePoint install to test it, but it will be something like this.

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$siteUrl = “http://mywebname/”
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl) 
$ctx.Credentials = $creds
$web = $ctx.Web 
$lists = $web.Lists
$ctx.Load($lists) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$item = $lists["Documents"].GetItemById(1)
$lastModified = $item.File.TimeLastModified
```

If you are unable to use the CSOM either, then I'm afraid you won't be able to retrieve the last modified time It is not accessible using standard WebClient calls.

Comment: Can you clarify what version of PowerShell this applies to?  OP may not be up to your level, as this doesn't work for me in 2.0.

Comment: You CAN use CSOM against SharePoint Online quite easily and there are plenty of examples around. You should also check out the [PnP](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-powershell) libraries for PowerShell as they generally make CSOM rather easier to get to grips with.